# Add class to images in JQuery click function

Tags: jquery

In click function all images,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".blurall").click(function(){
  $("[img='.jpg']").addClass("opacity");
  });
</script>
```

My css

```
.opacity{
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Not working any one help me!

Comment: Enclose your selector in quotes and put the whole thing in a [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). *Oh, and read the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/)/[JavaScript guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) for future reference.*

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are hoping to accomplish and what you have tried rather than just saying "not working". Thanks

Comment: How do the images tags look like?

Comment: Images don't have an `img` attribute. They usually have a `src` attribute (`img` is the **tag**). And usually the URL consists of more than just `.jpg` (`[...='...']` matches only the *exact* value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your selector is wrong, Use `img[src$='.jpg']` like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".blurall").click(function(){
      $("img[src$='.jpg']").addClass("opacity");
  });
</script>
```

try this...

Comment: `$(.blurall)` is also not valid.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure your DOM is [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) before this can be called. Additionally, you forgot the quotes around your first [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/). I swapped out the old `$.click` for the preferred [`$.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Lastly, updated your selector so that the `src` must [end with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) `.jpg` in order to be matched.

```
$(function(){
    $( ".blurall" ).on( "click", function() {
        $( "img[src$='.jpg']" ).addClass( "opacity" );
    });
});
```

Comment: what this "on("click", function() {".... This is not a function i think.. please refer back i didn't see like this before....